# can't pass this using arrow function in react?

Tags: javascript

I got undefined value passing **e** using arrow function

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={e=> this.handleCheck(this, 123)} />

handleCheck = (e, number) => {
console.log(number) //123
console.log(e.target.checked) //undefined
console.log(e.target) //undefined
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you passing `this` instead of `e` in `this.handleCheck(this, 123)` ?

Comment: Why do you *want* to pass `this`, you surely seem to know that `this` refers to your instance?

Answer (score 0):

In your code e.target will be undefined. It is because you are passing this as argument and `this` is reference to `React`class`.

case 1.

```
 <input type="checkbox"  onChange={e=> this.handleCheck(e, 123)}/>


Here `e` is value  not event. console.log(e) will print true on checked and false on unchecked.
```

Case 2:

```
 <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheck.bind(this)}/>//this is event here

    handleCheck(e)
    {
     console.log(e.target.value)// Here you will get value
    }
```

case 3:

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="me" onChange={this.handleCheck.bind(this,123)}/>//this is event here

    handleCheck(value,e)// if you bind method to this and pass extra arguments than you will get it in reverse order
    {
console.log(value)//123
     console.log(e.target.value)// me
    }
```